# three condition for a column one-to-many relation

Tags: mysql, sql, database

There are two table **Products** , **Colors**
There is a **one-to-many** relation between **products** and **colors**.

**Products Table :**
id,title,description

**Colors Table :** 
id,product_id,color_name

Now I wanna make a query that select **products** which have all (for example) three color in the colors table ('red','green','brown')

Comment: Please, do not hesitate to show us what did you try so far

Answer (score 0):

One method is:

```
select c.product_id
from colors c
where c.color_name in ('red', 'green', 'brown')
group by c.product_id
having count(distinct color_name) = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all the colors from `colors` table, then try the following query.

It will select all the colors and is not restricted to 3 colors

```
SELECT c.product_id
FROM colors c
WHERE c.color_name IN (SELECT DISTINCT color_name FROM colors)
GROUP BY c.product_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT color_name) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT color_name) FROM colors);
```

And if you need to fetch title and description of the product, then:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id in (
SELECT c.product_id
FROM colors c
WHERE c.color_name IN (SELECT DISTINCT color_name FROM colors)
GROUP BY c.product_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT color_name) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT color_name) FROM colors));
```

Answer (score 0):

HAVING is the way to go.

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.description
FROM products p
INNER JOIN colors c ON p.id = c.product_id
GROUP BY p.id, p.title, p.description
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) = 3
```